# Android NDK - Force library rebuild on configuration change

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, makefile, rebuild

**Is there a way to force the Android NDK to rebuild a particular library when changing build configurations in Eclipse?**

I am building building an Android Project using the Android NDK to build C++ libraries. I am using Eclipse with the Sequoyah plugin. Everything is set up and works well.

However, I have run into an issue with build configurations. You can manage build configurations by right-clicking the project->properties and then go to the C/C++ Build section. This allows you to create the traditional Debug, and Release builds that most C++ libraries depend on in some way.

Here is an example of my "Debug" configuration:

```
V=1 NDK_DEBUG=1 NDK_APPLICATION_MK=config/debug/Application.mk
```

These work well, except that when I switch back and forth between configurations, it does not trigger a rebuild of the libraries I am building. This would be expected for something like Visual Studio where each build config dumps to a different directory, but in Eclipse everything gets dumped to the same directory. I am forced to actually change relevant source files to trigger a rebuild. So what ends up happening is I end up running (for instance) in the Debug configuration but linking to libraries that were built in Release.

So my question is: **is there a way to force the NDK to rebuild a library when changing configurations?** I am aware of the -B command I can add, but that rebuilds *everything*, *everytime*. I would be OK rebuilding every time, if I could do it for just *one specific* library (in this case libBootInfo).

Here is what my root Android.mk file looks like:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := game$(MY_BUILD_CONFIG_EXTENSION)

# Include files are relative to the NDK root directly (fix by prepending with $(LOCAL_PATH))
# Source files are relative $(LOCAL_PATH)

#LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -landroid

# Add all source file names to be included in lib separated by a whitespace
LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=  ../../../../../../engine/code/main/mainandroid.cpp

# Module dependencies are expressed with LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES and LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES.
# we're building the "main" entry point, so it doesn't depend on much
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libDebug$(MY_BUILD_CONFIG_EXTENSION) libCore$(MY_BUILD_CONFIG_EXTENSION)

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

$(call import-module,libBdCore)
$(call import-module,libDebug)

##################################################################
## In addition to the core game library, we also build another
## *.so file here: "libBootInfo". This very small library is used
## by Java to find out which version of game to load based on
## the current build configuration.
##

LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := libBootInfo

# Add all source file names to be included in lib separated by a whitespace
# TODO: This path is relative to "android-ndk\build\core" which seems
#       different from the LOCAL_SRC_FILES in game above. It seems like
#       the build process leaves us in a different directory than we started.
#       We make need to look into a way to make sure that this path always 
#       works regardless of what came before it.
#
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../../../../engine/code/main/bootinfo.cpp

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: in your `Android.mk` file, the part that builds **libBootInfo** should not recalculate `LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)`. That's because `$(call my-dir)` actually brins the path of the last _make file_ included before this statement. If you move all **libBootInfo** part to the top of your `Android.mk`, it will work smoothly.

Comment: Also, the other comment is not correct too: _"Include files are relative to the NDK root directly"_. Actually, include files `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES` are relative to the _current directory_ which normally is the project root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was never able to get this working quite right. In the end I just created a batch file which wrote out an empty source file. That batch file is executed as part of a build step in Eclipse. I then included that source file as part of my library. Since the time stamp changes every time I build, it tricks ndk into rebuilding that library every time. I make sure that library is kept small and most code lives in other libraries, making the build time quite short.

Answer (score 2):

NDK build always refreshes the **.so** libraries in `lib/armeabi`. The `obj` directory, on the other hand, contains separate trees for debug and release builds, for each module.

Unfortunately, it's rather easy to screw this setup if your `Android.mk` does something not supported by tge framework.

For example, in your case, the long upgoing paths to cpp files (`../../../..`) may be a bad idea. I would advise to set `LOCAL_PATH` for each module, and avoid `../` in `LOCAL_SRC_FILES`.

Here is my suggested change for Android.mk:

```
ANDROID_MK_PATH := $(call my-dir)
LOCAL_PATH := $(ANDROID_MK_PATH)/../../../engine/code/main

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := game$(MY_BUILD_CONFIG_EXTENSION)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=  mainandroid.cpp
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libDebug$(MY_BUILD_CONFIG_EXTENSION) libCore$(MY_BUILD_CONFIG_EXTENSION)

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

##################################################################
## In addition to the core game library, we also build another
## *.so file here: "libBootInfo". This very small library is used
## by Java to find out which version of game to load based on
## the current build configuration.
##

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := libBootInfo
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := bootinfo.cpp

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

$(call import-module,libBdCore)
$(call import-module,libDebug)
```

**UPDATE**: Actually, using a module name suffix to separate the build configurations is, in my eyes, the best solution. This approach allows you to build and deploy more than one configuration at a time. For example, I use it when I have to optimize a library either to Tegra (without Neon) or to Snapdragon (with Neon): until recently, it was not easy to place two separate APKs on the Play Store, therefore I was packaging both `libv-neon.so` and `libv-tegra.so` into `lib/armeabi-v7a`.

I don't know what logic your **BootInfo** library includes, but if you are only deploying one library, you can avoid all the hassle with the following code in your Java class static constructor:

```
static {
    boolean loaded = false;
    while (!loaded) {
        try {
            System.loadLibrary("game" + nextExtensionAttempt);
            loaded = true;
        } 
        catch (Exception ex) {
        }
    }
}
```

An alternative approach would be to override the output directory `./obj`. For this purpose, you can add the following line to your `Application.mk` file:

```
NDK_APP_OUT := obj$(MY_BUILD_EXTENSION)
```

this way all the `.obj`, `.a`, and `.so` files (before they are *installed* into `libs/armeabi`) will be placed in a separate directory per configuration. Even easier, you can supply `NDK_OUT` parameter on the `ndk-build` command line, e.g.

```
ndk-build V=1 NDK_OUT=obj${MY_BUILD_EXTENSION}
```

This is very easy if you use Eclipse to maintain and choose your configurations. This makes it easy for Java to load the module, because it will always have the same name. But you can only deploy single configuration at a time.

Comment: This does not seem to be the case for me. NDK does not build *.so and *.a files into separate directories. Only the object files (*.o and *.o.d) are put into "obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/" and ".../armeabi/objs/". The actual compiled libraries are all found in "obj/local/armeabi/" with no regard for build configuration. Not to mention, the objs-debug folder appears to be based on APP_OPTIM flag which only supports "release" and "debug" but our engine has far more configurations than that.

Comment: Using `$(MY_BUILD_CONFIG_EXTENSION)` is actually a very good solution. in my opinion. This is more or less what I prefer in my projects. This gives very good control of what configurations are actually deployed to the device (_hint:_ it may be more than _one!). For an alternative solution, please see the **update** section of the answer.

Comment: The try/catch solution seems great to me, but one thing I am not clear on is how to stop the other versions of the libs from getting deployed to the device during debugging sessions (eg. Hitting F11 in Eclipse). For example, in "...\obj\local\armeabi" I have both "radgamed.so" and "radgamer.so". If I Run in the Debug configuration I want it to only find the libraries ending in "d" but it appears that the libraries ending in "r" also get deployed, so my try/catch will just succeed on the first one it tries. BTW: Thanks for the detailed answers! I really appreciate it!

Comment: I don't experience the problem you have. I mean, if I build one configuration. then only one `.so` file will make it into `libs/armeabi/` and eventually into the APK file. True, in `objs/` there are all linked (but unstripped) libraries.

Comment: I see the same thing. "libs/armeabi/" contains only the current build configuration libs. The APK file itself in the bin directory also only contains what was in "libs/armebi/". I believe the issue now is that all versions of the library are staying on the phone. If I manually delete the app and start fresh everything works, but if I then switch configs, the old library stays on the phone. Depending on the load order, it may find that old library first. I've started a new thread on that specific issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13041095/android-ndk-shared-libraries-staying-on-device