# How to force file to always build with Android.mk?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, adt, android.mk

I have a C++ file that is built for Android using the NDK and the file needs to be built every time I build in the directory, even if the file has not changed, because the file depends upon some `-D` flags that do change with each build that indicate the build timestamp and build SVN version.

On Linux using `gmake`, I have a rule that is never satisfied, so the file always builds.  On Android, I'm using an `Android.mk` makefile and I need to know how to force the file to always build, perhaps in a similar way with a dependency that is never satisfied, but I'm not sure how is this done in Android.mk files?

A similar rule seems to not have the desired effect (no effect seen):

```
$O/buildFlags.o: not_satified_dependency
```

Comment: Related (but it does not look like a dup): [Android NDK - Force library rebuild on configuration change](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12965550/608639). This bug report may give you inspiration: [ndk-build forces un-necessary recompiles](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=39810). Its the exact "feature" you are looking for.